# C++ multiple template calls

Tags: c++, templates

I have a question concerning multiple template usage in C++.
I have some stuff, but as it not compile, I am wondering if I made something wrong, or at least if it is possible to code this.

First the main call, the Building_Shop_A and Building_Shop_A classes are inherited from C_Building class, the Unit_People and Unit_Vendor_A classes are inherited from C_Unit class:

```
C_Building* pBuilding1;
C_Building* pBuilding2;

   pBuilding1 = myclass_Item->CreateBuilding<Building_House, Unit_People>("some_data_to_load");
   pBuilding2 = myclass_Item->CreateBuilding<Building_Shop_A, Unit_Vendor_A>("other_data_to_load");
   ...
```

'myclass' class templates implementation:

```
template< class T_Building, class T_Unit>
C_Building* myclass::CreateBuilding(char* inputdata)
{
C_Building* pBuilding;

    pBuilding = new T_Building();
    pBuilding->LoadBuilding<T_Unit>(inputdata);

   return pBuilding;
}

template< class T_Unit>
C_Unit* myclass::CreateUnit(char* inputdata)
{
C_Unit* pUnit;

    pUnit = new T_Unit();
    pUnit->LoadUnit(inputdata);
    //some unit stuff

   return pUnit;
}
```

C_Building class implementation:

```
template< class T_Unit>
void C_Building::LoadBuilding(char* inputdata)
{
C_Unit* pUnit;

    //init building data from 'inputdata'

    pUnit = myclass_Item->CreateUnit<T_Unit>(inputdata);
    //some optional unit stuff
}
```

C_Unit class implementation:

```
void C_Unit::LoadUnit(char* inputdata)
{
    //init unit data from 'inputdata'
}
```

To summary, in simple words, I would want to create couple of buildings/units with a very simple call (the first code lines of my question), because I will have a lot of couple like this, which can be mixed (not always same units for a given building), and then I guess this design will avoid me a lot of 'switch case' conditions.

Comment: "It does not compile" is not a good enough description of the problem. Please create a [mcve], empahsis on minimal.

Comment: `pUnit = new C_Unit();` should that be `T_Unit`?

Comment: Yes, it should be T_Unit. The error I got is "Error C2440 '=' : impssible to convert 'T_Unit' to 'C_Unit *' " on the line "pUnit = T_Unit();".

Comment: Okay, my bad, I just realize that I have forgot the "new" keyword.... what a noob I am... lol, now it compiles. In the question, the "new" keyword is present, but in my real code, it is not present

Comment: Happens, glad it has been solved :)

Comment: @Steph: Well, that's pretty obvious, but I suppose you come from a language where it's normal to create objects with `new`. C++ is quite different. It's possible, but there are quite some caveats. One of them is that it doesn't return the object itself, but a pointer to the object.